# Liferay-Primefaces ajax cast exception

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, liferay-6

I am trying to create working maven liferay-faces portlet archetype using primefaces 3.5. I downloaded basic maven web project arch and created the liferay-faces portlet arch. All dependencies for the .jar files are added in pom.xml file, after that i have created xhtml folder to store all jsf pages and configured the optional faces config files.

I have one table.xhtml page where i use primefaces  and backing @ManagedBean and @ViewScoped TableBean.java bean which uses cars list to populate primefaces table. The project was built successfully and deployed into glassfish 3.1 server on liferay-6.0.6 portal.

The problem is that when i add liferayjsf-1.0.0 portlet on the portal page and try to use primefaces ajax pagination table btw when i try to go to next pagination page for instance page 2, i got ExceptionAjaxImpl in the background.

Here is the stack trace:

```
   [#|2013-02-11T08:30:49.665+0000|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=30;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-8080-(5);|08:30:49,662 ERROR [ExceptionHandlerAjaxImpl:62] com.liferay.portlet.ResourceResponseImpl cannot be cast to javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.liferay.portlet.ResourceResponseImpl cannot be cast to javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
    at com.sun.faces.util.OnOffResponseWrapper.<init>(OnOffResponseWrapper.java:58)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.lifecycle.LifecycleWrapper.render(LifecycleWrapper.java:45)
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseResourceImpl.execute(BridgePhaseResourceImpl.java:117)
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgeImpl.doFacesRequest(BridgeImpl.java:128)
    at javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet.serveResource(GenericFacesPortlet.java:178)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:119)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:71)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:92)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:336)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:314)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:635)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeResource(InvokerPortletImpl.java:747)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.serveResource(InvokerPortletImpl.java:504)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processPortletRequest(LayoutAction.java:871)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:613)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:232)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:153)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:508)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:485)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:309)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:182)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:254)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:820)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:336)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:314)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:134)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processF|#]

[#|2013-02-11T08:30:49.666+0000|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=30;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-8080-(5);|ilter(StripFilter.java:309)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:182)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:222)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.cache.CacheFilter.processFilter(CacheFilter.java:442)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.etag.ETagFilter.processFilter(ETagFilter.java:45)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:254)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:81)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:179)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:240)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.threadlocal.ThreadLocalFilter.processFilter(ThreadLocalFilter.java:35)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(A|#]

[#|2013-02-11T08:30:49.666+0000|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=30;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-8080-(5);|bstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
|#]

[#|2013-02-11T08:30:49.668+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=30;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-8080-(5);|java.lang.ClassCastException: com.liferay.portlet.ResourceResponseImpl cannot be cast to javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
    at com.sun.faces.util.OnOffResponseWrapper.<init>(OnOffResponseWrapper.java:58)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.lifecycle.LifecycleWrapper.render(LifecycleWrapper.java:45)
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseResourceImpl.execute(BridgePhaseResourceImpl.java:117)
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgeImpl.doFacesRequest(BridgeImpl.java:128)
    at javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet.serveResource(GenericFacesPortlet.java:178)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:119)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:71)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:92)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:336)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:314)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:635)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeResource(InvokerPortletImpl.java:747)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.serveResource(InvokerPortletImpl.java:504)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processPortletRequest(LayoutAction.java:871)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:613)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:232)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:153)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:508)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:485)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:309)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:182)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:254)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:820)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:336)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:314)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:134)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:309)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.Application|#]......
```

---

I think that the problem is liferay-faces-bridge, when primefaces ajax is trying to send resourceRequest(after i click on the pagination page 2) request to the server request status code is 200(OK), but when server try to make response it can't convert the response properly from HttpServletResponse into ResourceResponse and render the jsf page to show the next 10 rows from the cars list.

So i am asking if someone have the same error to help me , or give me any sugestions what should i do.

Thanks in advance.